# CakePHP controller method to fetch data from multiple related tables

Tags: cakephp, controller

Currently i am working with CakePHP 3.x and have a following use case.

1. Department (id, name, description)
2. Designations (id, name, description)
3. Users (id, name, description)
4. DepartmentDesignations (id, departments_id, designations_id)
5. DepartmentDesignationUsers (id, department_designations_id, users_id)

Above mentioned are 5 different tables and their columns are listed in brackets. Following is the relationship between these.

1. Department has many designations. So in order to handle this i have created another DepartmentDesignations.
2. DepartmentDesignations has many users. So in order to handle this i have created DepartmentDesignationUsers.

I have defined following function in DepartmentsController and my expectation is that i need to get all the following information in single call.
- all the departments
- all the designations in each department (if any)
- all the users for each department designation (if any)

```
public function index()
{       
    $departments = $this->Departments->find('all')
    ->contain('DepartmentDesignations.Designations')
    ->contain('Users');       
    $this->set(compact('departments'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['departments']);        
}
```

I have also defined the following in DepartmentsTable.php

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Designations', [
        'joinTable' => 'department_designations',
        'foreignKey' => 'departments_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'designations_id'
    ]);

     $this->hasMany('DepartmentDesignations', [
        'className' => 'OrganizationManagement.DepartmentDesignations',
        'foreignKey' => 'departments_id'
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('DepartmentDesignationUsers',[
        'className' => 'OrganizationManagement.DepartmentDesignationUsers',
        'foreignKey' => 'department_designations_id'
    ]); 

    $this->belongsToMany('Users',[
         'joinTable' => 'department_designation_users',
         'foreignKey' => 'department_designations_id',
         'targetForeignKey' => 'users_id'
    ]);
```

I get the following response.

```
{
  "departments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Organization",
      "description": "",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "users": [],
      "department_designations": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "departments_id": 1,
          "designations_id": 1,
          "designation": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Brand head",
            "description": "",
            "level": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "departments_id": 1,
          "designations_id": 6,
          "designation": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "CEO",
            "description": "",
            "level": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Production",
      "description": "",
      "parent_id": 1,
      "users": [],
      "department_designations": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "departments_id": 2,
          "designations_id": 5,
          "designation": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Production assistant manager",
            "description": "",
            "level": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "departments_id": 2,
          "designations_id": 4,
          "designation": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Production head",
            "description": "",
            "level": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "R&D",
      "description": "",
      "parent_id": 1,
      "users": [],
      "department_designations": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "departments_id": 3,
          "designations_id": 2,
          "designation": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "R&D Manager",
            "description": "",
            "level": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Development",
      "description": "",
      "parent_id": 3,
      "users": [],
      "department_designations": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "departments_id": 4,
          "designations_id": 2,
          "designation": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "R&D Manager",
            "description": "",
            "level": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Purchase",
      "description": "",
      "parent_id": 1,
      "users": [],
      "department_designations": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I need the user information within department_designations array. So in this case what changes i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

> On the basis of your information there is no direct relation between
>   Departments and Users table, So you can not use contain that way for users.

Make it something like this:

```
public function index()
{       
  $departments = $this->Departments->find('all')
  ->contain('DepartmentDesignations.Designations','DepartmentDesignations.DepartmentDesignationUsers.Users');     
  $this->set(compact('departments'));
  $this->set('_serialize', ['departments']);        
}
```

See here: [Retrieving Associated Data in CakePHP3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data).